# Can reflection take place at the source in transmission lines?

Tags: transmission-line, reflection-coefficient

I have read about the reflection of voltage and current, when passed through a transmission line through a load if the load is mismatched with the characteristic impedance.

According to my understanding, the reflection happens because the voltage drop across the load is VL and in order to drop the exact amount of voltage across the load, The exact amount of current, IL passes the load and the remaining current is reflected from the load.

and the currents can be given by,

load current IL = forward current(I+) - reflected current(I-)

Am I right?

And also if the above given explanation is right, if in order to drop a voltage of VL across the load, the current generated by the source is insufficient, will the reflection take  place at the source resulting in the reflected wave going to the load which gives rise to the current equation,

IL = forward current(I+) + reflected current(I-)?

And is this what happens when the reflection coefficient is negative?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your assumptions are too simplistic. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflections_of_signals_on_conducting_lines

Comment: Related: [Transmission line reflection. I would like a non-mathematical explanation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/59208/11683)

Comment: @DaveTweed I have read your answer and come to an understanding that, when the transmission line is terminated with an open circuit, due to the high charge storage of voltage, the current is reflected in order to make the current zero (open circuit) and when the transmission line is terminated by a short circuit, as the current is high, the voltage is reflected to make the voltage zero (short circuit) and if the transmission line is terminated with an impedance, reflections of current and voltage take place simultaneously in order to maintain the values of voltage and current. Am I right?

Comment: @ShanmukhAkunuri It depends on how closely the impedance matches that of the transmission line. If it is exactly the same, then all the power is absorbed by the impedance. The voltage standing wave ratio, VSWR ("viswah") between reflected and forward waves is commonly used as a measure of how well the impedance is matched; a VSWR of 0 indicates a match, 1.0 indicates a total mismatch, i.e. short- or open-circuit.